# R Adding csv fille for ANOVA calculation

Tags: r

I want to load a csv file with 16 groups in R for ANOVA calculation.  However, when loaded, the summary is showing like:

```
> mark.data <- read.csv("teams.csv", header=TRUE, colClasses=c("numeric", "factor", "numeric"))
> summary(mark.data)
      Sl.            Group        Marks      
 Min.   : 1.00   1      : 5   Min.   :275.0  
 1st Qu.:17.25   11     : 5   1st Qu.:360.0  
 Median :33.50   10     : 4   Median :380.0  
 Mean   :33.50   12     : 4   Mean   :380.8  
 3rd Qu.:49.75   13     : 4   3rd Qu.:415.0  
 Max.   :66.00   14     : 4   Max.   :445.0  
                 (Other):40
```

Instead of showing 16 groups, it is taking only 6 groups `(1,11,10,12, 13, 14)` and the remaining groups are put into `others`.

I am newbie to R, and please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `summary` function only shows you the counts for the first six groups. In all likelihood, all groups have been imported correctly. To [see the counts for all 16 groups](http://www.modernstatisticswithr.com/thebasics.html#catdata1), you can use `table(mark.data$Group)`.